# Java connect timeout after number of successful connects and writes

Tags: java, sockets

I have some basic java socket client/server code to send a number of objects from client to server in a loop:

**Server**

```
    final ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8080);
    while (true) {
        final Socket socket = listener.accept();
        try {
            final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            final Object object = ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("error", e);
        }
    }
```

**Client**

```
public void go() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            sendObject();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error", e);
    }
}

private void sendObject() throws IOException {
    final Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
    final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(result);
    out.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

This works fine until around 16,000 objects have been sent.  The code then eventually times out with the following:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at uk.co.imrichardcole.socket.ObjectSocketClientBenchmark.sendObject(ObjectSocketClientBenchmark.java:39)
```

I assume I'm exhausting something by not properly cleaning up, but despite trying various combinations of `close` and `flush` I don't seem to be able to spot what it is.

Comment: Is there no error on the server side?

Comment: No error on the server side.

Comment: Is there any wait time between various client calls (in the loop) ? Can you show the full client code?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe original question updated

Comment: Just for testing: can you add a 100 ms sleep after each `sendObject()` ?

Comment: Recently I read about a case where the bind is failing because of not availability of ephermal ports on SO (I am unable to find that post). Looks like similar problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you keep creating a new connection each time through? Why not open the connection, and leave it open.  This way you won't run out of ports on the server.

Comment: @Mike He should certainly reuse the connection, but not for that reason. He isn't running out of ports in the server. He can't. He's only using one port in the server.

Comment: This isn't my final design, it was just a stepping stone towards it and I was left scratching my head about why it failed after a certain number of messages.

Comment: @KDM Looks similar how? How is a BindException similar to a connect timeout?

Comment: @EJP, I guessed, may be wrongly that the local ports are getting exhausted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're filling up the backlog queue with too many rapid connections. When that happens, Linux will simply not respond to further incoming connect requests (SYN packets).

You should use the same connection for as long as possible, and the same object streams too.

Comment: Thanks.  Final design won't look like this, but by adding a small sleep with the above design it works.

Comment: @EJP Doesn't an blocking accept remove the entry from the queue? If I remember right, this issue should come only when a server doesn't perform an accept. I might be wrong.